# LegacyJavaScriptObject -> Geopoint unrecognized in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I have a streambuilder which stopped working today and I'm trying to debug.

Versions:
firebase_core: 2.25.3
cloud_firestore: 4.15.3

It receives an object, with one of the fields being a Geopoint.

It works fine in Android and IOS, but on web it gives me an error:

> Expected a value of type 'GeoPoint', but got one of type 'LegacyJavaScriptObject'

I am trying to downgrade but haven't found the issue yet.

The object:

```
class Branch {
  final String id;
  ...
  final GeoPoint geo;


  Branch({
    required this.id,
    ...
    required this.geo,
  })

  factory Branch.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      Map data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

      GeoPoint safeGeo = (data['geo'] == null)
          ? const GeoPoint(0.0, 0.0)
          : data['geo']['geopoint'];

      return Branch(
        id: doc.id,
        ...
        geo: safeGeo,
      );

 ...
```

The Stream:

```
@riverpod
Stream<List<Branch>> myBranches(MyBranchesRef ref) {
  AppUser? user = ref.watch(authStateProvider).asData?.value;

  if (user is AppUser) {
    var stream = ref
        .watch(firestoreProvider)
        .collection('branches')
        .where('managers', arrayContains: user.uid)
        .snapshots();

    return stream.map((snapshot) =>
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Branch.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  } else {
    return const Stream.empty();
  }
}
```

The Screen:

```
return ref.watch(myBranchesProvider).when(
          data: (branchList) {
            ...
          },
          error: (e, st) => ...
          loading: () => ...
        );
```

The error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty,
dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>,
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#aa5da):
Expected a value of type 'GeoPoint', but got one of type 'LegacyJavaScriptObject'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>
  StreamBuilder:file:...
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem:? it is happening also with me!

Comment: Yes, there was a bug in nested fields. Make sure you update your pubspec to cloud_firestore: ^4.15.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Cloud Firestore bug.

Solved by updating to latest version:

```
firebase_core: ^2.25.4
cloud_firestore: ^4.15.4
```

The fix:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/12289